# PowerShell Boolean Expression

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, boolean, select-string

I am writing a powershell script but having a problem evaluating a boolean expression.

This is the line of code I am having a problem with:

```powershell
if (Get-Content .\Process2Periods.xmla | Select-String ((Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM") -quiet -ne True)
```

I am getting this error message when trying to run:

```powershell
Select-String : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ne'.
```

Please help me understand the issue.

Also for a little context, I am searching a file for a string and if it doesn't exist I want to execute what is in the if block. I didn't paste the code in the if statement because I don't believe it is relevant but please let me know if you would like to see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PowerShell is interpreting the `-ne` as being a parameter for `Select-String`.  To fix the problem, you can remove the `-ne True` part and use the [`-not` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847789.aspx) instead:

```powershell
if (-not (Get-Content .\Process2Periods.xmla | Select-String ((Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM") -quiet))
```

Note that `!` would also work if you prefer it over `-not`:

```powershell
if (!(Get-Content .\Process2Periods.xmla | Select-String ((Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM") -quiet))
```

---

Also, the `(Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"` part of the line above is unnecessary.  You can instead just do `Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"`.  See below:

```powershell
PS > (Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"
201502
PS > Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"
201502
PS >
```

Comment: You sir\ma'am are a God. Will check this answer in 6 minutes. Thank you very much.

Comment: @powershelluser Would like to mention that `(Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"` looks redundant and `Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM"` on its own would work just as well.

Comment: @Matt - I added that to my answer for you.  I only had the other version because I copied it from the OP's code.

Comment: @Matt - Nice, thank you Matt. One thing, I tried shortening the following line but was unable to get it to work: $monthMinus1 = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM" to $monthMinus1 = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1) -Format "yyyyMM". Do you know if there to pull this off? Thank you.

Comment: @powershelluser If you are going to do date manipulation then just leave it the way you had it. Your example in the question was redundant but the example in your comment requires something like what you already have. Leave it alone for you case.

Answer (score 1):

Your parenthesizing is off.

The `-quiet` and `-ne` arguments are being see as arguments to `Select-String`.

I'm unsure what command you wanted `-quiet` to apply to (I expect `Select-String`) but you need to wrap the entire `Get-Content ... | Select-String ...` bit in `()` and then use `-ne "True"` or `-ne $True` (depending on whether you want string or boolean true).

```
if ((Get-Content .\Process2Periods.xmla | Select-String ((Get-Date) | Get-Date -Format "yyyyMM") -quiet) -ne $True)
```

Comment: -quiet is for select-string

Comment: @Matt Yeah, I realized that after I wrote that sentence and looked at the `select-string` help. Thanks.

Comment: iCodez answer worked for me and his seems to be less complicated/easier to read. I appreciate the answer though. Thank you.

Comment: @powershelluser For this case it is more direct, yes. The general case requires knowing about the extra grouping though. Go ahead and accept his answer though.